# Cakephp 2.5: add control on js, css, images using cake controller

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, cakephp

I am building app using the [`CakePHP`](http://cakephp.org/) and [`AngularJS`](https://angularjs.org/).

While developing AngularJS application, I found that we are creating considerable large number of js, html files.

I want to return these js/html from CakePHP controller.

In Such way that:

From client side request will come as like(for js file):

```
http://example.com/javascripts/file/jquery
```

In above url

```
>                 **javascripts** is Controller name,
>                 **file** is action name in that controller,
```

AND
       I want that in response, it will return content of [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) file where as `jquery.js` reside in **"webroot/js/jquery.js"** OR at any other folder.

Same with html and CSS files.

Does anyone had tried in this way?

> I just want to control the js, html, CSS files from CakePHP
>   controller.

If you have any another solution for the same then please...

Answer (score 0):

why you are using html, if cakephp use the ctp just a recomnedation "keep it simple" copy the content of the ???.html in View/Javascript/???.ctp, in the controller just use this;

```
<?php $this->layout = false; ?>
```

If you put the following at the top of the view this work too.

now if you want use the angular just need use in the view o default layout:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('angular')?>
```

and can add more scripts.